# nvidia-331 +Nvidia Optimus (K2000M, Lenovo W530) + Ubuntu 14.04 + external display on VGA not recognized

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, vga

Currently I have nvidia-331 installed. But the same problem appeared also with nvidia-343:

If integrated graphics is set in bios: everything works fine. (except the VGA port, obviously)

If nvidia optimus is set in bios: everything works fine except that the system does not recognize a second display attached on the VGA port.

If discrete graphics is set in bios: black screen with blinking cursor (no ctrl-alt-Fx possible, only cold-reboot).

Problem: I need a second display (and it was working before some updates f'd up the system somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by downgrading to ubuntu-drivers-common=1:0.2.91.4

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-drivers-common=1:0.2.91.4

sudo aptitude hold ubuntu-drivers-common
```